# How to generate multiple registration ID for Google Cloud Messaging through a single Google account

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am working on enterprise level application and it uses GCM. The app is going to be distributed among different clients and their multiple different agents. Since GCM works by generating registration id(signing in to Google account) as well as a device with sync that Google account. What if i want multiple registration ID against a single Google account. because it is quite difficult to create thousands of Google accounts and making them sync to thousands of devices.
I want a single account sync with multiple devices performing GCM. I tried it on two devices but only the device which is registered first performs well. Other didn't get push notifications.

Comment: That's an interesting experiment. Did you get the same registration ID for both devices?

Comment: No that's not working. Since Registration ID is supposed to be a device and app registration id. So one registration id is not applicable for other device.

Comment: I don't understand. What did you get when you registered the second device? Was the registration successful? Did you get different registration IDs for the two devices?

Comment: Yes :) the way you are asking question provides me solution. Registration ID is different for different devices even if both devices affiliated with single Google Account. It is working thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since my comments helped you find the solution, I'll write an answer based on them :

Each device is assigned a different registration ID by GCM, even though they are both using the same Google Account.
In order to push a message to both devices, simply send the message to both registration IDs.